# How i can change Background Color when Validator active

Tags: asp.net

How i can change Background Color when Validator active
in Asp.net i want to change background color to RED when validator is active befor postback on pagevalidating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function fnOnUpdateValidators()
        {
            if (typeof Page_Validators != 'undefined') {
                for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
                {
                    var val = Page_Validators[i];
                    var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
                    if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null)
                    {
                        if (!val.isvalid)
                            ctrl.style.background = '#FFAAAA';
                        else
                            ctrl.style.backgroundColor = '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and in form load

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "val", "fnOnUpdateValidators();");
```

Answer (score 1):

It Simple.

Use If Condition.

```
var val = Page_Validators;
                    var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
                    if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null)
                    {
                        if (!val.isvalid)
                            ctrl.style.backgroundcolor = '#dddddd';
                        else
                            ctrl.style.backgroundColor = '';
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather add/remove class names from validator rather that setting the color directly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid = function () {
        Page_IsValid = AllValidatorsValid(Page_Validators);
        setValidatorStyles();
    }
});

function setValidatorStyles() {
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        var inputControl = document.getElementById(Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);
        if (null !== inputControl && !Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
            WebForm_AppendToClassName(inputControl, "invalidElement");
        } else if (null !== inputControl) {
            WebForm_RemoveClassName(inputControl, "invalidElement");
        }
    }
}
```